# Self bricked with bootloader

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot

I install a Flashify on my Huawei Ascend P7 to make my .img files run and I can install a Custom ROM, because always when I try to install it from ADB it shows

```
FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)
```

All files what I want to boot from ADB, shows this line. I add to boot a twrp.img file to get TWRP and install ar CustomROM

When I turn on my phone, blinks red, 2 times green and then again the same. Also Power + Vol Up or Down, doesnt work, even I cant run a update from SD Card, and HiSuite doesn't show my phone as connected...
Similar problem is in this post - http://forum.xda-developers.com/ascend-p7/help/unfortunately-boot-failed-information-t2908514

There's full CMD lines from my try to run recovery and boot

```
The system cannot find message text for message number 0x2350 in the message file for Application.

Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Not enough storage is available to process this command.

C:\...\ADB Flash Tools>fastboot flash recovery recovery.img

target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (12510 KB)...
OKAY [  0.480s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)
finished. total time: 0.481s

C:\...\ADB Flash Tools>fastboot boot BOOT.img
creating boot image...
creating boot image - 9660416 bytes
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  0.363s]
booting...
FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)
finished. total time: 0.365s
```

Only thing I can get into fastboot.

Whats the problem? And how I can get back my phone to work?

Answer (score 3):

***Commands not allowed*** shows when the bootloader is locked. Try `fastboot oem get-bootinfo` to get the lock status. This [guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/ascend-p7/general/unlock-bootloader-huawei-ascend-p7-l10-t2830641) shows you how to unlock the bootloader.

Comment: yeah, it shows `(bootloader)  locked OKAY [  0.002s]`
i cant even turn on my phone, only i can get fastboot

Comment: Now go through the guide to unlock it then you'll be able to send any conmand.

Comment: i cant even turn on my phone, only i can get fastboot. also i cant get emui recovery

Comment: If so, try flashing your phone first. Firmware + instructions here: http://consumer.huawei.com/nz/support/products/downloads/ascend-p7-nz.htm

Comment: i tried to `fastboot update update.zip` and it shows `error: update package has no android-info.txt or android-product.txt`

Comment: This ain't a flashable zip. You have to install it by buttons combo (Volume up + Volume down + Power). Unzip the file and copy the dload folder in the root of a SD card.

Comment: I cant get into EMUI recovery or update. Only what I can get is fastboot mode

Comment: I don't tell you to access recovery! This can't be flashed through recovery neither!

Comment: Huawei mobile devices are flashed this way! The flash file you'd downloaded contains a folder named dload, in this folder there is a file named update.app. So, to flash the phone, simple unzip the zip and copy it contents into the root of an SD card, put that card into the phone then power the phone by holding Volume up + Volume don buttons at the same time. The process should begin.

Comment: these files are `folders: cust, meta-inf, patch, system and update.app`?

Comment: Wait don't unzip UPDATE.APP file!

Comment: maybe we  can chat somewhere? skype or some facebook!?

Comment: Unzip just the file you downloaded before, you'll get a folder named dload, copy that folder into an SD card, put the card in the phone. Power the phone holding down : Volume up button and Volume down button

Comment: Im already did that... all what I get is flashing red light

Comment: Maybe your battery is low

Comment: nop, I do that plugged on charger

Comment: Are you able to remove the battery ? This should reset the phone and you'll be able to flash.

Comment: nop, it cant be able :(